# HTTP ERROR 500 when running to linux server?

Tags: server, mysql, php

I have this PHP code for importing excel to mysql using PhpSpreadsheet in xampp. This code is OK when running in windows environment but if I hosted it to a Linux Server(Ubuntu 22.04) using XAMPP Linux got an error "HTTP ERROR 500". I've installed all packages and extension needed for PhpSpreadsheet based here on phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io documentation. If this error is for the server side what should I do? Please help

These are my codes for my import file

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "mark/import1",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Mark\\Import1\\": "src/"
    }
},
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "mark"
    }
],

 "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.28"
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.1"
    }
}
}
```

**import code**

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_import');

 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
 use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

  if(isset($_POST['save_excel_data']))
  {
   $fileName = $_FILES['import_file']['name'];
   $file_ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   $allowed_ext = ['xls','csv','xlsx'];

  if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext))
  {
    $inputFileNamePath = $_FILES['import_file']['tmp_name'];
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileNamePath);
    $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

foreach($data as $row)
{
            $fullname = $row['0'];
            $email = $row['1'];
            $phone = $row['2'];
            $course = $row['3'];
    
    $studentQuery = "INSERT INTO students (fullname,email,phone,course) 
                            VALUES('$fullname','$email','$phone','$course')";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $studentQuery);
            $msg = true;    
}
 }
 }
```

Comment: Look at the slashes in your code. This is for a Windows system. For a Linux system they go the other way. $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileNamePath

Comment: @David hi sir. I've already did that but still problem exist and also run this in a ubuntu desktop22.04 but no luck

Comment: You have changed ALL the wrong slashes everywhere?

Comment: @David yes sir by changing to forward slash /

Comment: @Jos I dont see any apache2 from /var/log

Comment: @Jos the apche2 was included in XAMPP but i didnt see any error.log /opt/lampp/apache2 (scripts,htdocs and conf)

Comment: I understand the log file is located elsewhere in an XAMPP installation. Please find it and look up the actual PHP error that caused the 500 error message. I will remove my previous comments.

Comment: @jos sorry but i dont see any error logs :(